# Relational Database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, relational-database

Say if I have 3 tabeles: Reader, Book, Readers_book.

## Reader

#email, name, password

## Book

#BookID, FK BookName, BookType

## ReadersBook

#ReaderBookID, BookName, FK email

How would I perform an insert statement to populate these tables when a Reader wants a new book. Given the Reader will already have an email, name and password. would I use a join, or perform two separate insert statements?

or would anyone be able to reccomend a better way to model this kind of data?

Comment: AFAIK you can use join only in a select. First write the depending rows (Book and Reader / if not present) and then insert to ReadersBook

Comment: will 'INSERT OR IGNORE' work on a table with an AUTOINCREMENT row

Comment: You can override any column, even autoincrement. No idea what you mean with IGNORE. You should wrap your insert in a COMMIT.

Answer (score 0):

a more flexible model would be ...

[image]

... and you'll have to insert into each table separately.

Comment: Actually there is no difference to the OP's model except it's show as class diagram. So it's not more flexible.

Comment: using ids to relate data means not having to change things like "bookname" in more than one place, and i'd call that more flexible.

Comment: Yes. That was not that obvious. Repeating the table name in the columns is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use join in insert, update and delete command, but you can used more than one statement and seperate with ';'

insert into table1(col1,col2) values(?,?);insert into table2(col1,col2) vslues(?,?)